# Covariance matrix of a random vector

Tags: matrices, random-variables, matlab, covariance

According to the [documentation of Matlab](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html#buo3tdl-1) regarding the function `cov()`: "if A is a vector of observations, then `cov(A) = C` is the **scalar-valued variance**". But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Definition) the covariance matrix of a vector of random variables is the matrix whose entries are the covariance between the $i$ and $j$ columns of the vector.

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that in the MATLAB documentation of the case of A being a vector of observations, the random variable vector has length (dimension) = 1, and there are several observations of this one-dimensional random vector. In this case, per the Wikipedia definition, the vector has only one column, so the covariance matrix consists entirely of the covariance between the 1 and 1 column, i.e., the variance.

Think in general of an m by n matrix, in which there are m data points, each consisting of an n dimensional random variable, In your called out MATLAB case, m = 1.